# Multiple column names in PutHBaseRecord Row Identifier Field Name property in NiFi

Tags: database, hbase, apache-nifi

I have a simple flow of extracting rows from Oracle Table and putting it into Hbase via NiFi.

To Extract Data from DB I am using "QueryDataBase Table" and put to HBase I am using "PutHbase Record" Processor.

Usually, whatever is the primary key of my Table I am using it as a "Row Identifier Field" in putHbaseRecord.

My problem is arising when there is Composite Primary Key, As Row Identifier Field property in putHbase Record processor is not taking multiple columns.

Any help in this will be really Helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is not currently possible with PutHBaseRecord. It would require a code change to the processor to allow the specifying multiple field names for the row id, and then it would have to get them and from each record and concatenate them together to form the row id value.

It might be better to make the property be a record path expression that creates the row id. This way if you want a single value you just put something like '/field1' and if you wanted a composite value you'd do something like "concat('/field1', '/field2')".

Comment: @Appy22, you can use similar approach given in this SO thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55005395/row-identifier-with-multiple-fields-in-puthbaserecord-in-apache-nifi