# Row Identifier with multiple fields in PutHBaseRecord in Apache Nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

I have Json array like this;

```
[
    {
        "item_id": "",
        "timestamp": "",
        "type": "",
        "value": ""
    },
    {
        "item_id": "",
        "timestamp": "",
        "type": "",
        "value": ""
    }
]
```

I want to create row key for HBase as like this **: item_id timestamp type**

But PutHBaseRecord waits one field from me. What can I do?

---

Can I do something like that?

For record reader = **JsonPathReader**

And, rowId = concat($item_id, $timestamp, $type) ????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **`UpdateRecord`** processor before **`PutHbaseRecord`** processor.

Defines **Record Reader/Writer controller** services to include newly added field(row_id)

Add **new property** in UpdateRecord processor as

```
rowId

concat(/item_id, /timestamp, /type)
```

Then in **PutHBaseRecord** processor use the **rowId** in place of `Row Identifier Field Name` property value.

Refer to [this](https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/189642/update-the-contents-of-flowfile-by-using-updaterec.html) link for configure/usage of UpdateRecord processor